# C# Xamarin Placing EditText above ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, xamarin, android-edittext

I want to place a SearchBox above my ListView, but when I do that my EditBox will appear next to my ListView. How can I place it above the ListView?

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:background="#edf0f4">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="#d0d4db"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_marginRight="15px"
    android:layout_marginTop="15px"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you will need to set `LinearLayout` orientation to "Vertical" in order to have `EditText` above your `ListView`, like this:

`android:orientation="vertical"`.

and here is a full code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="#edf0f4">

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittext" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="#d0d4db"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
        android:layout_marginRight="15px"
        android:layout_marginTop="15px"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I set the textpadding in the EditView something more to the right?

Comment: That is question for another thread but you can set android:padding in EditText control. Btw if my answer was helpful for you please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.